# argument of type AbstractControl is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have built a form where I have implemented a form validation that simply displays an error message when the user leaves the email or password field blank. It works perfectly but my problem is that I set the email and password to "AbstractControl" instead of "String" so when I am trying to authenticate them with firebase, I get this error message saying "argument of type AbstractControl is not assignable to parameter of type string". I believe the problem is that I set email and password to abstract control vs setting it to a string. How can I override this and allow the validation to go through and the authentication? Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <form [formGroup]="formgroup">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
             <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
             <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email" name="email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="email.hasError('required') && email.touched">
            <p>*Email is required</p>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="password" name="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item *ngIf="password.hasError('required') && password.touched">
             <p>*password is required</p>
           </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      <button clear ion-button (click)="login()">Submit</button>
      </form>
</ion-content>
```

**TS File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
/**
 * Generated class for the ProfilePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

  email: AbstractControl;
  password: AbstractControl; 
  formgroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(public formbuilder: FormBuilder, public aAuth : AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({
      email:['',Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    });

    this.email = this.formgroup.controls['email'];
    this.password = this.formgroup.controls['password'];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  login(){
   this.aAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
     e => {console.log(e)}
     )
  }

  goToSignup(){
    this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the error messages says it all. The error is because `signInWithEmailAndPassword` requires `string`s but you've called it with `AbstractControl`s.

You can get the value of an `AbstractControl` using the `value` property on it.

Change your `login` method to this:

```
login() {
  this.aAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value)
    .then(e => console.log(e))
}
```

**Quick Tip:**

Not sure why you created the `email` and `password` properties on your Component, when you could have easily gotten the value of the form using `this.formgroup.value` and then you could have also used destructuring to extract the `email` and `password` from the form value and then pass it to the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method:

```
login() {
  const { email, passowrd } = this.formgroup.value;
  this.aAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(e => console.log(e))
}
```